# A random text as output

Tags: c, codelite

My goal is a function that returns the same text as I wrote in stdin.
As a result of compilation of the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char chain[990];
int znaki()
{
scanf("%s", chain);
int i=0;
do{
    putchar(chain[i]);
    i++;
}
while(chain[i]!=10);
return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
znaki();
return 0;
}
```

I get:

> MyOwnText
>
> MyOwnText
>
> and
>
> many
>
> lines
>
> of
> some
> random text just like cat /dev/random in linux

The first line is my input.
Why?

Comment: What did you expect the output to be? Why is this not a sane output?

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    putchar(chain[i]);
    i++;
} while(chain[i]!=10);
```

This code prints characters from chain (and further) until finds a char with code 10. As the buffer is uninitialized, it is filled with some random data from other programs. And you see that data.
Probably, you wanted to write something like

```
do {
    putchar(chain[i]);
    i++;
} while(i != 10);
```

which would print first 10 chars from the array.

And by the way, the code seems to be vulnerable to a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an array.
2. You asked the user for a word, and you stored it in the beginning of that array.
3. You then printed the array.

It's pretty obvious to me why the input you wrote was printed out.

Comment: You didn't understand me. INPUT:MyOwnText OUTPUT:MyOwnText                 &      52                32    *%!

Comment: That's exactly what I would expect as the output for that input.  What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

`chain[]` does *not* have the value of 10.

`chain` is filled with non-white-space characters - that is what `"%s"` directs `scanf()` to do: scan and save non-white-space `char`.  `10` is typically `'\n'`, a white-space.

```
char chain[990];
scanf("%s", chain);
...
while(chain[i]!=10);
```

Instead use `fgets()` to read *lines*.

```
int znaki(void) {
  char chain[990];
  while (fgets(chain, sizeof chain, stdin) != NULL) {
   int i=0;
   while (chain[i] != '\n' && chain[i] != '\0') {
     putchar(chain[i]);
     i++;
   }
   return 0;
 }
```